# Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить программу, чтобы она работала корректно. Меняла слова child и Child на children и Children соответственно. С++

Tags: c++

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void zmina(char*);

int main() {
    char*str = new char[255];
    cout << "You need to enter text. You can use the offer." << endl;
    cout << "Where child play vith toys. Child are child because child. But not children."<< endl << endl;
    cin.getline(str, 255);
    zmina(str);
    delete[] str;
    return 0;
}
void zmina(char* str) {
    char* stri = new char [255];
    char* slovo = strtok(str, " ,.-");
    while (slovo != NULL) {
        if (slovo == "child") strcat(stri, "children");
        else if (slovo == "Child") strcat(stri, "Children");
        else strcat(stri, slovo);
        slovo = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");
    }
    char plus[1] = { '\0' };
    strcat(stri, plus);
    cout << stri;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char* stri = new char [255];
```

это у вас некоторый буфер букв (НЕ СТРОКА), в который вы делаете регулярно `strcat`, т.е. вызываете функцию работы со строками

ну так превратите буфер сначала в строку, т.е. добавьте закрывающий строку символ `\0` -

```
stri[0] = 0
```

а вы это зачем-то только в конце делаете

```
char plus[1] = { '\0' };
    strcat(stri, plus);
```

в конце это делать как раз не надо